# How do I list installed MSI from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

We recently switched our Windows software packages from RPM (cygwin) to MSI (wix). Having a native packaging is a much welcome change and we intend to stick with it. However, MSI feels overly complicated for what it does and doesn't seem to provide some basic abilities. But I'm probably mistaken.

Is there a way to list all installed MSI from the command line ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mabybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(VS.85).aspx) is a good starting point for you example VB Script from MSDN:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & _
    "\root\cimv2")

Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product")   

If colSoftware.Count > 0 Then

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile( _
        "c:\SoftwareList.txt", True)

    For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
        objTextFile.WriteLine objSoftware.Caption & vbtab & _
        objSoftware.Version
    Next

    objTextFile.Close

Else
    WScript.Echo "Cannot retrieve software from this computer."

End If
```

Comment: I would have prefered something to use from the command line, but this will do. Thanks.

Comment: Go ahead and use the script from the command line, then. Use cscript.exe to run it, and do not output to file but to stdout (like so: WScript.Echo objSoftware.Caption & vbtab & objSoftware.Version). All the FSO stuff is not needed then anymore.

Answer (score 14):

You may use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell) and [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation). Here is a one liner:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product
```

Here is help for the `Get-WmiObject` [cmdlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmdlet):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315295.aspx

Here is a sample where we select the first installed program and format it as a table:

```
PS C:\Users\knut> Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product |
>> select -First 1 | ft Name, Version, Vendor -AutoSize
>>

Name             Version  Vendor
----             -------  ------
AWS SDK for .NET 1.2.0200 Amazon Web Services Developer Relations
```

Comment: See similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569

Comment: For some reason doesn't list '3CXPhone for Windows' version 16.3.0.220 that I cannot get removed from the list (says it's already uninstalled). Its not even under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. `winget upgrade` does see it as well as that version 

Comment: Ah it's parked under SysWoW64:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\3CXPhone for Windows 16.3.0.220`

Comment: For reference for all(?) the locations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937569/273668

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is what you need but you can query the uninstall list from the command line with:

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Comment: Excellent:  However, there is a small typo.  It should read: 'HKLM' not 'HLKM' (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).